# select nothing from first table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Quick question regarding sql syntax
If I have 3 tables (hereby reffered to 1,2,3) and want to select everything from  `table 2,3` tables depending on if an id is present in table 1, how do I do that, I.E "select nothing" from table 1? As for now I select everything from `table 1`.

```
SELECT * FROM [Content] pc, [test] Dc, 
[Swg] Swg where pc.Id=Dc.Id and pc.Id=Swg.Id  order by pc.Id
```

Comment: NOT EXISTS(Select ID from [Content] ) put this in where condition and remove pc.Id=Dc.Id..

Comment: Your question is ambiguous.  One interpretation is that you want everything from table 2 (Dc) and everything from table 3 (Swg), but nothing else.  If so, DoctorMick has given the answer.  If that's not what you were really asking, then you need to reword the question.

Comment: anders, your example doesn't make much sense. Why should you want to combine a dc with an swg only because they happen to have the same ID? swg.id should identify an swg and dc.id a dc, so even if both happen to have the same ID, that doesn't say anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to select everything from tables test and SWG, even if there is no match in table Content?

If so, a RIGHT join would do the trick:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
   Content
      RIGHT JOIN test ON content.ID = test.ID
      RIGHT JOIN SWG ON Content.ID = SWG.ID
```

If you're looking for everything from test and SWG but only if there is a matching ID in CONTENT, then this should work:

```
SELECT 
    test.*
    , SWG.*
FROM
   Content
      JOIN test ON content.ID = test.ID
      JOIN SWG ON Content.ID = SWG.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

So you just don't want to see the columns from table 1?

```
SELECT Dc.*, Swg.*
FROM [Content] pc, [test] Dc, 
[Swg] Swg where pc.Id=Dc.Id and pc.Id=Swg.Id  order by pc.Id
```

That assumed pc = table 1, dc = table 2 and swg = table 3

Answer (score 0):

e.g. if table 1 is Content (pc alias in your query):

```
SELECT Dc.*, swg.*
FROM ....
```

So, you have to specify the table aliases you want to select from. `*` alone will select all columns from all referenced tables

Answer (score 0):

You may Tried This

SELECT pc.* ,Dc.* ,Swg.*
    FROM [Content] pc, [test] Dc, 
    [Swg] Swg where (pc.Id=Dc.Id or pc.Id=Swg.Id)  order by pc.Id

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from 
T1 left join T2 on T1.id=T2.id 
Where T1.id in (select id from T3 where...etc.)
```

This way, you will get everything from **T1**, and matching **T2** values if **T1** values matches values from T3 without getting this **T3** table values